# How many money per television has been increased?

Tags: economics

> In a shop where it sells televisions, all of them with a price of 1596\$, they managed to sell 42 televisions. After an increase of price of those televisions, they sold 38 televisions and earned 1140\$. Find the increase of the price of the televisions.

This is a quite easy and simple problem, but we get different answers:

$\\ \mathbf{My\ method:}$ I simply found the $\frac{\$}{televisions}$ of each time, for the time before the increase: $$\frac{1569}{42}=380\$/television$$ and after the increase $$\frac{1140}{38}=30\$/television$$ so the final answer I thought it was $$380\$/television-30\$/television=350\$/television$$ they increased $350\$ $ per television. Is there anything wrong with this method? If so, what is it?

Comment: The numbers in the question don't work out. Compared to the first scenario of making $1596 with 42 TVs, the second scenario sells roughly 10% fewer TVs but results in a nearly 30% drop in revenue. The price of TVs went *down*, not up.

Comment: Check your numbers.